# Doesn't GUIMiner work on Windows 8?

Tags: windows

I use [GUIMiner](http://guiminer.org/) to mine bitcoins using my graphics card, and in a pool.
I've upgraded to Windows 8 this morning, but now GUIMiner won't launch!

All I get is the icon in the taskbar for a few seconds, and it disapears. I have no error message, no windows, and no error logs.

I have tried launching the application as an administrator, and in "Windows XP" and "Windows 7" compatibility modes.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What happens when you launch it from the command line? If you can get some kind of error message, post it on the [GUIminer issues system](https://github.com/Kiv/poclbm/issues?state=open).

Comment: Moreover, I'm not sure this question is a good fit for SE. It should actually probably better be filed there to boot.

Comment: This is getting weird, nothing is shown when launched via commandline either

Comment: I think you're best troubleshooting this on the issues system linked above. I had a friend try on Win8, and it at least starts up.

Comment: Yes, it feels like I'm the only one with this problem. I've added an issue.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized, since upgrading to windows 8 is a pretty specific scenario (and this site is mainly for the purposes of compiling lasting bitcoin knowledge).  Just wanted to comment so you knew it wasn't any poor reflection on you, Manu--this is just how these sites are curated.  Hope the GUIminer issues system can get you some help!

Comment: agreed, + it now works with the latest (beta) drivers from ATI :)